# SQL - Объединение двух таблиц по временным условиям

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть 2 таблицы, одна содержит сведения о устройствах, другая информацию о тестировании этих устройств.

Таблица Divice:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица Tests:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть два запроса к этим таблицам, первый выводит все устройства в базе данных:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где, Last_Test_Date - Дата запуска самого последнего теста для данного прибора.

Второй запрос требует вывести только те приборы которые проходили тестирование в определенный промежуток времени.
Т.е. промежуток с начала теста по его окончание должен пересекается с указанным периодом

Например - вывести все приборы проходившие тестирование с

09.01.2018 по 10.01.2018 т.е.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вопрос-то в чём? как написать условие отбора только тех записей, которые попадают в промежуток *с 09.01.2018 по 10.01.2018*?

Comment: Да, все устройства нахожу по запросу : select t.* from Device t join (SELECT Device_ID, MAX(Test_Start_Date) as Last_test_start_date FROM Tests group by Device_ID) m on t.Device_ID = m.Device_ID, но с дополнительной сортировкой по времени не выходит

Comment: Под текстом вопроса есть ссылка "править". Добавляйте дополнительную информацию в вопрос, а не в виде комментариев.

Comment: *промежуток с начала теста по его окончание должен пересекается с указанным периодом* Промежутки пересекаются, если начало первого было не позже (при непременном наложении - строго раньше) конца второго и начало второго не позже (раньше) конца первого.

Answer (score 0):

Иcправил:               `select t.* from Device t join (SELECT Device_Guid, MAX(Test_Start_Date) as Last_test_start_date FROM Tests WHERE Test_Start_Date <='24.12.2018 10:48:59' AND Test_Start_Date >= '23.12.2018 10:48:59' group by Device_Guid  ) m on t.Device_Guid = m.Devic`

Comment: Запрос неверен. Если тест начался до указанного периода, а закончился после него, то...

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @d1 DATE='2018-12-20',@d2 DATE='2018-12-23'

SELECT d.Device_Name,d.Parameter_1,d.Parameter_2,MAX(Test_Start_Date) AS Last_Test_Date
FROM Device as d
     INNER JOIN Tests t ON d.ID_Device=t.ID_Device
WHERE t.Test_Start_Date<=@d2 AND t.Test_End_Date>=@d1
GROUP BY D.Device_Name,d.Parameter_1,d.Parameter_2
```